# Appropriate iterative linear solver for an eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, eigensystem, krylov-method

I'm trying to solve a generalized eigenvalue problem

$$Ax = \lambda Bx, \quad A = A^\top > 0,\; B = B^\top > 0$$

with $\lambda \approx \sigma$ using [Rayleigh Quotient Iteration (RQI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient_iteration) (RQI is applied to $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$, but the $B^{-1/2}$ cancels from the final formulas):
$$
(A - \mu_k B) \tilde x_{k+1} = B x_k\\
x_{k+1} = \frac{\tilde x_{k+1}}{||\tilde x_{k+1}||}\\
\mu_k = \frac{x_m^\top A x_m}{x_m^\top B x_m}\\
\mu_0 = \sigma, \quad x_0 = \text{random vector}
$$
I've decided to use some iterative method to solve
$$
(A - \mu_k B) \tilde x_{k+1} = B x_k
$$
for $\tilde x_{k+1}$, since I do not want to store $A$ and $B$ explicitly. I only wish to code computing $Ax$ and $Bx$ products.

The matrix is symmetric, but not positive definite, otherwise I would have used conjugate gradients method. Which method would you suggest? Are there any pitfalls when using Krylov subspace methods with RQI?

Comment: @nicoguaro $A > 0$ is a standard notation to denote a positive definite matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Further_properties .

Comment: $A \geq 0$ is psd, $A > 0$ is pd. Yes, both matrices are positive definite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your matrices are large, why not use a library like [ARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/)? The shift-and-invert mode of ARPACK will help you calculate the eigenvalues close to $\sigma$.

There are interfaces to ARPACK for most high-level programming languages used for numerical computations (Fortran, C, Python, MATLAB, etc.).

For example, a quick tutorial for Python can be found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/arpack.html) (reasonably small, dense matrices), or [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh) (large, sparse matrices, available only in operator form).

Later edit: I read your post more carefully and noticed you are looking for a way to solve the shift-invert linear system... so why not try [MINRES](http://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/minres/) or [SYMMLQ](http://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/symmlq/)? Both algorithms are based on a Lanczos (3-term Arnoldi) iteration specifically designed for symmetric (but not necessarily positive definite) matrices. SYMMLQ should perform better if $A$ is non-singular.

Comment: Since I'm trying to solve near-to-singular system $(A - \mu B)$ when $\mu$ is close to an eigenvalue, I'd better stick with MINRES instead of SYMMLQ. But I have troubles with finding some canonical pseudocode for MINRES,

Comment: Look [here](http://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/minres/minres-matlab.zip). It is a rather concise MATLAB implementation of MINRES with lots of helpful comments (and a "tutorial" PDF).

Comment: That implementation is mostly unreadable, already tried. I found one good [here](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~vorst102/ITER2.ps.gz)